# Simple excel creation does not open file is corrupt

Tags: c#, error-handling, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to create a simple excel file with multiple sheets using open xml, unfortunately the file does not open after it's being created.

After the file is generated, when I open it with Microsoft Excel it says

> We found a problem, do you want to recover as much as we can?

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreedDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filePath,
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
    WorkbookPart wbPart = spreedDoc.WorkbookPart;

    wbPart = spreedDoc.AddWorkbookPart();
    wbPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

    Sheets sheets = wbPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

    foreach (var sheetData in excelSheetData)
    {
        // Add a blank WorksheetPart.
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = wbPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

        string relationshipId = wbPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart);

        // Get a unique ID for the new worksheet.
        uint sheetId = 1;
        if (sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Count() > 0)
        {
            sheetId = sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
        }

        // Give the new worksheet a name.
        string sheetNameToWrite = sheetName;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sheetNameToWrite))
        {
            sheetNameToWrite = "Sheet"+sheetId;
        }
        // Append the new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
        Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = sheetName };
        sheets.AppendChild(sheet);
    }

    //wbPart.Workbook.Sheets.AppendChild(sheet);
    wbPart.Workbook.Save();
}
```

On trying to Repair in excel gives below message

```xml
-<repairedRecords summary="Following is a list of repairs:">

<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Worksheet properties from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)</repairedRecord>

</repairedRecords>

</recoveryLog>
```

Comment: Have you tried comparing the corrupted file to the failed after it was repaired by Excel to see what exactly changed? (You could do that using the Open XML Productivity Tool that comes with the OpenXML SDK)

Comment: did not know that we had a tool to it, let me check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen this?
http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm

The necessary steps to create a functional excel file with multiple worksheets in OpenXML (that work for me) are as follows:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(path, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {
            spreadsheet.AddWorkbookPart();
            spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();

            spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Append(new BookViews(new WorkbookView()));

            WorkbookStylesPart workbookStylesPart = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>("rIdStyles");
            Stylesheet stylesheet = new Stylesheet();
            workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet = stylesheet;
            workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Save();

            for (int worksheetNo = 1; worksheetNo < worksheetCountYouWantToCreate; worksheetNo++)
            {
                string workSheetID = "rId" + worksheetNo;
                string worksheetName = "worksheet" + worksheetNo;

                WorksheetPart newWorksheetPart = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                newWorksheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet();

                newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData());

                // write data here
                // ...
                // ...

                newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

                if (worksheetNo == 1)
                    spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets());

                spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>().AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet()
                {
                    Id = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(newWorksheetPart),
                    SheetId = (uint)worksheetNo,
                    Name = worksheetName
                });
            }
            spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
        }
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the solution. But i am receiving another one now, while trying to open the file throws an error that its not valid

     repairedRecords summary="Following is a list of repairs:">

     <repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part</repairedRecord>
     <repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml part</repairedRecord>

Comment: @Dilip what data are you writing into the file?

Comment: its string, has reference to charts

Comment: Each sheet (tab) needs to have unique name. This error is also shown when 2 or more sheets have the same name (among other errors)